# The code cannot be executed in the Firefox browser

Tags: json

How can I do it in the Firefox browser?

[Look](http://random-go.blogspot.com/)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var adfly_id = 16627167; 
    var popunder_frequency_delay = 0; 
    var adfly_protocol = 'https'; 
</script> 

<script src="https://cdn.adf.ly/js/display.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want to run this code in the FF console?

Comment: On Blogger uses but does not know why Firefox is not available

Comment: Hello Tsone and welcome to SO! You may want to refine your question to describe the exact problem you encounter in firefox.